# Build Boost 1_70_0 to MS V Studio 2019 C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost

I've been using Boost libraries with MS Visual Studio C++ for a long time, in different versions of VS and Boost.

Relating to Boost, after download and unpack, the build process has been:

**1.-** Run `bootstrap` from VS prompt.

**2.-** In `C:\boost_some_ver\project-config.jam`, edit the line `using msvc ;`
and change to `using msvc : 14.0 ;`

In this case, `14.0` correspond to **VS Express 2015**

**3.-** Build the libraries with the command:

```
bjam release debug threading=multi --build-type=complete --toolset=msvc address-model=64 stage
```

Now I must build the libraries for **VS Studio 2019** and want to know what toolset correspond to this compiler.

Ie. What **x.xx** number correspond to VS Express 2019 C++ in `using msvc x.xx ;`

Answer (score 12):

To build the Boost_1_70_0 libraries for MS Visual Studio 2019, the toolset seems be 14.2 although it seem not necessary modify the file **project-config.jam**.

Leaving that file "as is", and using the "developer command prompt to MS 2019" to build the libraries (in my case):

**32 bits libraries:**

```
b2 release debug threading=multi --build-type=complete --toolset=msvc stage
```

**64 bits libraries:**

```
b2 release debug threading=multi --build-type=complete --toolset=msvc address-model=64 stage
```

The builder automatically generates libraries for **msvc-14.2** in both versions, debug and release.

Comment: Where's the documentation for this, it would be great to look up what each option you have provided means

Comment: with boost 1.75, vs2019, x64 bit native command promt and your 64 bit library build command still produces an output like that:  "default address-model    : 32-bit
    - default architecture     : x86"